# How to get year and month of Bootstrap Datepicker as it on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

I'm new to this datepicker and I don't know how to get the month and year string on change events `changeMonth` and `changeYear`.
Here is a link to the plugin: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

The issue is that onchange captures only the transition from months to years. I am only able to get the day/date of the selected date, and nothing is selected during transition.

I tried to grab text from the div, but I am always one selection too late. How can I get the month and year of the value that is selected after a transition.

To clarify: 
getYear() when we see all 12 months after changing from the decade view

getMonth() when we see days after the month view

Heres my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vj3cdzbc/2/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Get month:

```
 $("#datepicker").datepicker().on('changeMonth', function(e){ 
   var currMonth = new Date(e.date).getMonth() + 1;
 });
```

Get year

```
 $("#datepicker").datepicker().on('changeYear', function(e){ 
   var currYear = String(e.date).split(" ")[3];
 });
```

Comment: This seems to assume you click > to go forward. What happens when you click < back?

Answer (score 0):

Get Month and Year

```
 $("#datepicker").datepicker().on('changeDate', function (e) {
    var pickedMonth = new Date(e.date).getMonth() + 1;
    var pickedYear = new Date(e.date).getFullYear();               
 });
```