# C# Date format error in run time VS2005 Application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a datetime picker dtOtMonth which I need to display only month and the year.So I have formatted it as follows in the event of form load.

```
dtOtMonth.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dtOtMonth.CustomFormat = "MM/yyyy";
```

But when I try to edit the date with up/down arrows in run time it gives me the following error.

Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
>         Message="Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime."
>         Source="mscorlib"
>         StackTrace:
>              at System.DateTime.DateToTicks(Int32 year, Int32 month, Int32 day)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker.SysTimeToDateTime(SYSTEMTIME s)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker.WmDateTimeChange(Message& m)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker.WmReflectCommand(Message& m)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker.WndProc(Message& m)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd,
>   Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd,
>   Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SendMessage(Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ReflectMessageInternal(IntPtr hWnd,
>   Message& m)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmNotify(Message& m)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox.WndProc(Message& m)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd,
>   Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr
>   wndProc, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(Message& m)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Control.DefWndProc(Message& m)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmKeyChar(Message& m)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker.WndProc(Message& m)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd,
>   Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
>              at Attendence_Module.Program.Main() in E:\HR System\HRProject\Attendence_Module\Attendence_Module\Program.cs:line
>   17
>              at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
>              at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>              at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>              at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>              at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>              at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: I opened a winforms project - dragged a `datetimepicker` - copied your code in the `Form_Load` event, and all works. can it be some other thing in your code?

Comment: See the following http://stackoverflow.com/a/1608804/1071091 it might help you

Comment: WOW found something.. VS-2005??? make haste and switch to 2015!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As OP discovered, the error occurrs when only the month changes, it is possible to change to a date that doesn't exist (e.g. "February 31st").

There are a couple of ways to prevent the error. One way is to ensure that the `DateTimePicker` always uses the first day of the month. Here's a quick example that makes sure the `Day` property of the value of the `DateTimePicker` is always set to 1. In this example, I use a read-only textbox to show the output:

```
public MyTestForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    SetDateTimePickerFirstOfMonth();
    UpdateTextbox();
}

private void SetDateTimePickerFirstOfMonth()
{
    DateTime current = dtOtMonth.Value;
    if (current.Day != 1)
    {
        DateTime newValue = new DateTime(current.Year, current.Month, 1);
        dtOtMonth.Value = newValue;
    }
}

private void UpdateTextbox()
{
    int year = dtOtMonth.Value.Year;
    int month = dtOtMonth.Value.Month;

    txtResult.Text = string.Format("Year is {0} and month is {1}", year, month);
}

private void dtOtMonth_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetDateTimePickerFirstOfMonth();
    UpdateTextbox();
}
```

Using this code, I can still use the arrow keys to change the year or month in the `DateTimePicker`, and it will ensure that the DateTimePicker value is always set to the first of the selected month, even if a specific date is selected.

Here's a screenshot, of the demo application. The textbox changes its value as soon as the DateTimePicker's value is changed.

[image: Example Winform]

Comment: @code_Finder That's great! :) Feel free to mark the anwer as accepted if it helped you solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It needs a day to increment a value. Seems like it's parsing a date and can't do that as there is no day.

Comment: Exactly that's what I found

Answer (score 1):

At last I found the bug.

In a date time picker if not we initialize the default date even though we take month and year only, inside it takes default date(here today's date in my case).

So when I change the month, the selected date remain same for each month.Therefore today is 30th March 2016 and when I try to decreases the month by one it is February and the date time picker try to initialize the date 30th to February and it generates the error.

In my case as far as I use month and year I leave the date apart.

I solved this by initializing the date for 1 st of the month on form load event  where each and every month has a day1 st (one) not like 29th,30th,31th

```
dtOtMonth.Value = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);
dtOtMonth.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dtAdvanceStartDate.CustomFormat = "MM/yyyy";
```

Here are some very useful links where I found this is a .NET bug.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/553375/system-argumentoutofrangeexception-year-month-and-day-parameters-describe-an-un

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/69b10b5b-a034-426e-a045-2bed8a1637a3/bug-in-datetimepicker-control?forum=winforms

Comment: Glad you fixed the issue, but it doesn't sound very robust. If you only need the Year and Month, maybe you could store these values as two separate integer values, instead of using a DateTime. Here's an example of how to extract these values from the DateTimePicker: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29454651/717088

Comment: I've added an answer, with an example of how to do it in a Winforms project.